# What to do when others change my question fundamentally?

Tags: discussion, edits

On Stack Overflow I asked a specific question about a [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagram. The next day someone changed my question to say it was not about UML diagrams and instead focused on a secondary issue I was having even though I very clearly showed the UML diagram, the code I was working with, and where I was having the primary issue.

They changed not only the question title, but the content of the question and the tags of the question. This is a fundamental change of the question as a whole which would only serve to prevent me from getting a complete answer.

I was of course able to change the question back, but I could not see a way to contact the user who did this or seek help about it and the ability of someone else to do this makes me very uncomfortable especially since I wasn't notified of the change.

How should I ordinarily proceed in such a situation?

Comment: Please ask this question on MSO, we are not subject experts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: MSO? I don't understand your acronyms. Besides, I thought Meta was where I am supposed to ask questions about StackExchange itself. Or was that wrong? I know I am giving details about Stack Overflow, but unless the ability to edit other people's questions is unique to Stack Overflow it seems like the question can be answered here.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Indeed, but this question is specific to an SO question, and they can judge better if the edit was okay.

Comment: If you want to discuss editing in general, remove the details of your specific question (it will be a duplicate of some other previously asked question in that case). If you want to discuss editing your specific question MSO is where you want to be.

Comment: Pro-tip: Please stop using "EDIT" section headers in your questions.  I looked at 3 of yours and you have at least 1 in all 3 questions (including one with "EDIT", "EDIT 2", "EDIT 3".  If you have to make an edit, just edit the entire question so the additional material makes sense.  No one wants to read the whole post to find that you clarified it at the end.  If someone really wants to see what changed, there is a revision history.

Comment: +1 @psubsee2003 that's my policy too